How to make Gish stick to the ceiling?
I'm trying some deathless runs on Super Meat Boy and for some levels Gish comes in handy, but I find it inconsistent because I can't always do what I want to do.
So there may be two reasons: the character is bugged (which is possible) or I'm not using the correct controls.
As far as I know, keeping R2 pressed makes Gish stick to walls, but that's not enough to stick to ceilings. Sometimes, keeping jump (X) pressed seems to work, but I still fall often.
So what's the deal? What am I doing wrong?

Ok, I've figured out how to use Gish.
It's true that keeping R2 pressed makes Gish stick to walls. To make him stick to ceilings you have to jump (X) and also it's needed to have enough vertical velocity to adhere, or he will just bounce away.
I noticed that Gish tends to get stuck in corners, in that case you have to press jump (X) and keep it pressed in order to move and remain sticked to the ceiling.
So, to make it short:

R2 to stick to walls
R2 + X to move on ceiling (with enough initial vertical speed to stick)

